# If i help in zakat collection then can i receive a portion of it?

Tags: zakat

Assalamu Alaikum,
One of my friends told me that person who engages in zakat work can receive zakat too.

- Does it also apply to people who are not poor and rather have enough money?
- Can they still receive zakat for helping collect zakat? And how much can they receive?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].